# java agent for IBM domino lotus

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I studied some tutorials in domino designer 9 now I want to make java agent but I didn't find any tutorials, Can any one give me good tutorials to learn java agent please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that you'll find a clear, concise step-by-step tutorial.  I've found some generic code samples, and there are samples for specific tasks (you know, like "How do I send a message?")   What I did to learn was to take a small task, perhaps one already written in LotusScript and make it in Java.  Open a database.  Open a view.  Create a document.  Delete a document.

Comment: I can make new agent and studied some agent examples found in the web then I run it by right click on agent then Run Agent it show agent-log window but I don''t understand the content of this log

Comment: The Agent log shows when the agent started and stopped and how many documents were processed (which it reports even if you didn't even attempt to process a document.)  You can optionally write to it yourself with the logAction() and logError() methods of the Log class.  You can create an instance of the log with the createLog() method of the Session class.  Now if you're new to Lotus/Domino, most of this will be baffling to you.  I can't help you with that in this forum.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, Do you have any tutorials or example for this topic?please help me If you can!!

Comment: No, everything I've managed to find you can find with Google just as easily.

Comment: Ok thanks for your effort